# use of doGet() in Java to write HTML code

Tags: java, html, servlets

I want to write an HTML code inside Java, using a servlet. I read about the method `doGet()` and I wrote this simple example

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  IOException { 
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(  ); 
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
out.println("<H1>Hello from a Servlet</h2>");
```

But it doesn't give anything in the browser, can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: How have you configured the servlet in your servlet container?

Comment: try to check the server logs first

Comment: maybe an out.close(); could help

Comment: i think you should post the entire class, the problem might be that you didn't inherit from Servlet, or even that you don't know how to publish it into an application server, anyway - we need more information.

Comment: Hint: if the editor removes your salutation, then it's for a reason. Obfuscating it to get around that reason is *not* a good idea.

Comment: A couple of notes about example: 1. always set headers before getting writer; 2. add Override annatotion when you override a method to avoid  errors like this

Answer (score 2):

The standard `PrintWriter` which you get by calling `response.getWriter();` doesn't automatically flush its buffers. It's a bug/feature.

Add `out.flush()` at the end of `doGet()`.

Also note that `PrintWriter.close()` **does not flush**. It's a bug; `PrintWriter/PrintStream` are the only output classes which don't flush on close.

**[EDIT]** To make sure that no other problem confuses you, add a breakpoint in the method and run it in the debugger. You should also add the annotation `@Override` to make sure your method signature is correct.

Comment: Aaron, are you sure that flushing is necessary? It seems you may just write, without flushing.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. What happens is that the output goes into the buffer of the `PrintWriter` which wraps the underlying `OutputStream`. The Servlet API will flush the `OutputStream` but it won't close or flush the `PrintWriter`. That means the output is never flushed to the stream, hence you don't get anything in the browser.

Comment: Nonsense. If you ever experienced this, then you're using a broken `HttpServletReponseWrapper` implementation.

Comment: @BalusC: You mean broken implementations like Tomcat 5.5, Tomcat 6 and 7?

Comment: No, a custom `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation somewhere in your app (check all filters). It is not properly delegating `flush()` or `flushBuffer()` method to `super`. The OP's code -although containing a HTML syntax error- works perfectly fine in a blank webapp project on all Tomcat versions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't actually override doGet. You missed the `ServletException` exception.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Overriding methods can throw less exceptions (but never more).